# Chromosome Deletion Notation in Cancers

Tags: cancer, genomics, cytogenetics

The cancer literature often refers to the deletion of certain sections of a chromosome (e.g. "17p del" or "Del(17p)" for the deletion of chromosome 17's p-arm.)

Does this mean both alleles of the chromosome were deleted for the specified cytoband (i.e., copy number analysis would show zero in this case)? Or does it mean one of the alleles was deleted, and thus one remains (copy number analysis would show a copy number of 1 in this case)?

Thanks